# How to add new gridstackitem with directive?

Tags: gridstack

Using gridstack.io, I want to dynamially have a button that can "add a widget" into a specific area. I have a component "" that I want to add dynamically into the grid.

Given my following definition for my gridstack, How can I make it such that if I add a button that when you click on it, adds a new directive in the top-left corner, how do I accomplish that?

I have the following directive:

grid-stack-directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any; // JQuery

@Directive({
    selector: '[gridStack]'
})
export class GridStackDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() w: number;
    @Input() animate: boolean;

    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer
    ) {
        renderer.setElementAttribute(el.nativeElement, "class", "grid-stack");
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let renderer = this.renderer;
        let nativeElement = this.el.nativeElement;
        let animate: string = this.animate ? "yes" : "no";

        renderer.setElementAttribute(nativeElement, "data-gs-width", String(this.w));
        if(animate == "yes") {
            renderer.setElementAttribute(nativeElement, "data-gs-animate", animate);
        }

        let options = {
            cellHeight: 80,
            verticalMargin: 10
        };

        // TODO: listen to an event here instead of just waiting for the time to expire
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);
        }, 300);
    }

}
```

grid-stack-item-directive.ts:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[gridStackItem]'
})

export class GridStackItemDirective {
  @Input() x: number;
  @Input() y: number;
  @Input() w: number;
  @Input() h: number;
  @Input() minWidth: number;
  @Input() canResize: boolean;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer
  ) { 
    renderer.setElementAttribute(el.nativeElement, "class", "grid-stack-item");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let renderer = this.renderer;
    let nativeElement = this.el.nativeElement;
    let cannotResize: string = this.canResize ? "yes" : "no";
    let elementText: string = '<div class="grid-stack-item-content">' + nativeElement.innerHTML + '</div>';
    // TODO: Find the Angular(tm) way to do this ...
    nativeElement.innerHTML = elementText;

    renderer.setElementAttribute(nativeElement, "data-gs-x", String(this.x));
    renderer.setElementAttribute(nativeElement, "data-gs-y", String(this.y));
    renderer.setElementAttribute(nativeElement, "data-gs-width", String(this.w));
    renderer.setElementAttribute(nativeElement, "data-gs-height", String(this.h));
    if(this.minWidth) {
      renderer.setElementAttribute(nativeElement, "data-gs-min-width", String(this.minWidth));
    }
    if(cannotResize == "yes") {
      renderer.setElementAttribute(nativeElement, "data-gs-no-resize", cannotResize);
    }
  }
}
app.component.html:

<h1>My First Grid Stack Angular 2 App</h1>
<section id="demo" class="darklue">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Demo</h2>
                <hr class="star-light">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div gridStack w="12" animate="true">
            <div gridStackItem x="0" y="0" w="4" h="2">1</div>
            <div gridStackItem x="4" y="0" w="4" h="4">2</div>
            <div gridStackItem x="8" y="0" w="2" h="2" canResize="false" minWidth="2">
                <span class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></span> Drag me!
            </div>
            <div gridStackItem x="10" y="0" w="2" h="2">4</div>
            <div gridStackItem x="0" y="2" w="2" h="2">5</div>
            <div gridStackItem x="2" y="2" w="2" h="4">6</div>
            <div gridStackItem x="8" y="2" w="4" h="2">7</div>
            <div gridStackItem x="0" y="4" w="2" h="2">8</div>
            <div gridStackItem x="4" y="4" w="4" h="2">9</div>
            <div gridStackItem x="8" y="4" w="2" h="2">10</div>
            <div gridStackItem x="10" y="4" w="2" h="2">11</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery-ui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/jquery-easing/dist/jquery.easing.1.3.umd.min.js"></script>

    <!-- underscore and gridstack --> 
    <script src="node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-extra.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/gridstack-demo.css">

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

    <!-- freelancer stuff -->
    <script src="app/js/freelancer.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/freelancer.css">

  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a "router" inside your `gridStack` directive - it will get a string represent the type of the desired component and load the it with `ngIf`

```
<div customGridStackItem1 *ngIf="itemType == 'stackItem1'"></div>
<div customGridStackItem2 *ngIf="itemType == 'stackItem2'"></div>
<div anotherGridStackItem *ngIf="itemType == 'anotherStackItem'"></div>
```

that way you will only load the component you need in each grid item